# CSS Combo box dropdown position

Tags: css, combobox, drop-down-menu

I searched the web but couldn't find a good answer for HTML/CSS designs:

- I have a menubar docked to the right of my screen
- The menu bar contains `select` elements (comboboxes) with a fixed width
- Sometimes the content of those comboxes is too big to fit that fixed width

Here the current behavior I'm noticing:

- in normal position, the choice is simply clipped and that's fine by me
- in dropdown position, the dropdown 'box' isn't clipped but is aligned to the left side of the combobox; as a consequence it goes beyond the right side of the screen and part of it is simply unreadable

  [image: example]

What I would like to do is force the dropdown box to align with the **right** of its parent combobox.

**Any way to do that in CSS - or even JS I guess but not the preferred solution...?**

Comment: If you remove all your styling, the browser dosent automaticly send it to the right?

Comment: @Marco, just tested it on chrome and it's true. the dropdown will be outside the browser window and even outside the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll be out of luck here with pure css.
you could look for a [javascript combobox](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml) though and style that with css.

Comment: Yup, it seems there's no way to do this with pure CSS. I just laid out my page differently...